# How to invisible a field based on complex condition in odoo10?

Tags: attr, odoo-10, invisible

I add a field in `account.payment`.

```
bank_id = fields.Many2one('res.bank', string="Bank")
```

when i clicked the register payment button in account.invoice then it is opened a register payment wizard.

I want to invisible the `bank_id` based on the condition

```
journal_id.type not in bank
```

How it is possible in odoo??

in `xml` I add a condition like this.

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('journal_id.type', 'not in', ['bank'])]}"
```

How to correct the condition??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this situation you can not apply direct `attrs` so you have to take one compute boolean field to check the journal type and based on that field make bank_id visible or invisible

in account.payment

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

class account_payment(models.Model):
     _inherit = "account.payment"

     bank_id = fields.Many2one('res.bank', string="Bank")
     check_journal = fields.Boolean(string="Journal Type", compute='_check_journal_type')

     @api.depends('journal_id')
     def _check_journal_type(self):
         if self.journal_id.type == 'bank':
             self.check_journal = False
         else:
             self.check_journal = True
```

in account.payment view

```
<field name="check_journal" invisible="1"/>
<field name="bank_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('check_journal', '=', True)]}"/>
```